# Why isn't Dorian raining on the southeast side?

Tags: tropical-cyclone

Dorian is currently passing over the Carolinas but its eye is only brushing the shore. However there's a side of Dorian that isn't raining:

[image]

Is this unique to Dorian?

Comment: @JessieCalderon Hello you have a rotating system. The rain bands inside the cyclone are rotating with the entire cyclone. Moisture is sucked from the ocean and probably enters the system on the SE side. But you have a rotating system. Air parcels are rising and rotating as well.

Comment: It depends on the orientation of the vortex and the direction in which the environmental winds are bringing in the moisture plus the shear.

Comment: https://journals.ametsoc.org/doi/pdf/10.1175/2009MWR2921.1